Glitch exporting decimated models
Since updating to 4.1, every single time I try to export a model that I have used the decimate modifier on (usually collapse), I get this glitch right after the model exports, and then the exported glb file contains no information. I always apply the modifier and all transforms before exporting! Has anyone seen this, or have any idea what might be causing it? Thank you!
